# Override inline CSS Div tag

Tags: html, css

I have a site containing the following line :

```
< div id="German" style="display: inline-block" >
```

The display tag is inline, and I would like to override this in the CSS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to read about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `!important` to override inline styles...

```
#German {
    display: static !important;
}
```